# How to Properly use Select Max() in Eclipse

Tags: java, sql, eclipse

I am working on a school project where I must interact with an access database.  I'm attempting to

```
SELECT Max(GameID) AS MaxID
FROM Games
```

However, This query when ran through the Eclipse application I built only returns in the console

```
SQL Exception: UCAExc:::4.0.3 Column not found: GameID
SQL State: S1000
Vendor Error: -421
```

I have checked the access database and the column DEFINITELY EXISTS.  I ran the query in the access database and it worked in there as well.  I'm not sure what I'm missing or if this is possible.  How can i grab the highest value of gameID's?

here is the connection to the database

```
ResultSet rs = null; //will hold record that get returned
Statement stmt = null; //will hold the SQL statement we want to run

try
{
    //2. Establish the connection
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/Public/ZaccaroBlottoDB.accdb");

    //3. Create the statement
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String theQuery = "SELECT Max(" 
            + "GameID)"
            + " As MaxID"
            + " FROM Games"
            + " WHERE (1=1)";

    //4. Execute the statement
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(theQuery);

    //5. Process the results
    while (rs.next())
    {
        int gameID = rs.getInt("GameID"); //note the type and the field name from the DB


        System.out.println(gameID);
        //addGameIDFTF.setText(Integer.toString(gameID +1));
    }//while

    //6. Close the Connection
    rs.close();
    conn.close();           
} 
catch (SQLException ex)
{
    System.out.println("SQL Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    System.out.println("SQL State: " + ex.getSQLState());
    System.out.println("Vendor Error: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    ex.printStackTrace();
} //catch
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?  `rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)` or `int gameID = rs.getInt("GameID")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is the value that you are retrieving. As you have mentioned the alias name to be MaxID you should get MaxID from result_set instead of GameID

Hence, It should be

```
int gameID = rs.getInt("MaxID");
```

instead of

```
int gameID = rs.getInt("GameID");
```